# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even though code has try/catch within async/await

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, async-await

I realize this may seem like a duplicate of other questions, but I have looked at every suggested SO question I could find before posting this, and I am looking for help on this specific scenario, as none of the other answers have worked for me.

I have a Node/Express app that is initializing a single MongoDB connection to be used by a REST API.  The first step is to connect to the MongoDB instance.  If the initial connection fails, it will throw an error as expected.  I am using async/await with a try/catch block inside of it to handle that.  Everywhere I have looked says that this should be sufficient to catch these async/await promise rejections, but I keep getting an error about an UnhandledPromiseRejection no matter where I throw in a `.catch()` or try/catch for my code (as suggested in other SO posts).

In this link, for instance, I have pretty much the same thing that is described in the error handling section, but the problem still exists.

https://javascript.info/async-await

Here's the error (I know what is causing the error itself - I have the MongoDB service stopped right now - but I am trying to fix the unhandled promise rejection error):

`(node:15633) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15633) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13802) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/allen/scripts/lysi/eosMain/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:562:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/allen/scripts/lysi/eosMain/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:316:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/allen/scripts/lysi/eosMain/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)`

and here's my code:

```
exports.mongoConnect = async (dbName, archiveDbName, userName, password) => {

    // Auth params
    const user = encodeURIComponent(userName);
    const pass = encodeURIComponent(password);
    const authMechanism = 'DEFAULT';

    // Connection URL
    const url = `mongodb://${user}:${pass}@localhost:27017?authMechanism=${authMechanism}&authSource=admin`;
    let client;

    try {
        // Use connect method to connect to the Server
        client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, poolSize: 10, autoReconnect: true, reconnectTries: 6, reconnectInterval: 10000 }).catch((e) => { console.error(e) });

        db = client.db(dbName);
        archiveDb = client.db(archiveDbName);

        console.log(`Succesfully connected to the MongoDb instance at URL: mongodb://localhost:27017/ with username: "` + client.s.options.user + `"`);
        console.log(`Succesfully created a MongoDb database instance for database: "` + db.databaseName + `" at URL: mongodb://localhost:27017/`);
        console.log(`Succesfully created a MongoDb database instance for database: "` + archiveDb.databaseName + `" at URL: mongodb://localhost:27017/`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error connecting to the MongoDb database at URL: mongodb://localhost:27017/` + dbName);
    }
}
```

that is being called from app.js like this:

`mongoUtil.mongoConnect('myDb', 'myArchiveDb', 'myUser', 'myPassword');`

I even tried putting that line in a try/catch block, or adding the promise-style `.catch()` onto the end of it, with no change.

I can't seem to figure out why it's still complaining about not handling the promise rejection.

**EDIT:**

Here's the whole app.js file:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// This is where the mongo connection happens
var mongoUtil = require( './services/mongoUtil' );
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

const jwt = require('./helpers/jwt');

var api = require('./routes/api.route')

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api', api);

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use(jwt());

app.use('/users', require('./users/users.controller'));

MongoClient.Promise = bluebird

mongoUtil.mongoConnect('myDb', 'myArchiveDb', 'username', 'password');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;`
```

Comment: can you make sure your MongoDB server is running?

Comment: It is not currently running, but that's not really the problem I was asking about.  This started when I accidentally tried to start my app without MongoDB running. 
 It threw this error so I wanted to investigate what caused it, because it seems like I am not properly handling the error that occurs when it cannot connect to MongoDB.  The actual problem is solved by starting MongoDB, but that doesn't fix the fact that promise rejections aren't being handled correctly.

Comment: ah ok! got you. Why not use the `Promise` notation? `MongoClient.connect(...).then(() => { // all good }).catch((error) => { // error here })`

Comment: He also said he already tried that, all is in the question ...
@NellaGnute: Can't see anything obviously wrong in your code, will upvote and wait for a more knowledgeable person to answer as I am curious!

Comment: Does `MongoClient.connect` even return a Promise?

Comment: A problem with your current use of `.catch(…)` is that `client` will become `undefined` after you handled the error by logging it. Don't use `.catch(…)` syntax (unless for default values) when you use `await` and handle rejections with `try`/`catch` already. However, this doesn't appear to be the cause of the unhandled rejection in your post.

Comment: @Rashomon The official docs for the driver seem to indicate that it's just a callback, but by using async/await, that makes it return a promise, as far as I know.  I'm trying to be as current as possible with this application, so I opted for that syntax rather than doing `new Promise()` etc.

Comment: @Bergi My apologies - I should have mentioned that the `.catch()` was added while trying to troubleshoot the issue.  It wasn't part of my original code that I had when I first saw the issue.  I'll take it out to avoid the undefined issue you described.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html Checked this docs and it says it returns `null`...?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine as you can see in the screen shots below. I think the problem lies with whatever is calling mongoConnect()

[image: Connecting on wrong port]
[image: Successful connection]

Comment: Maybe it's a versioning issue?  Mine works fine when MongoDB is running, but when it's not running and fails, I get an unhandledPromiseRejection error and you don't for some reason.  I'm running this with "npm start" on Node 10.15.1 and NPM 6.7.0

Comment: I was on node 8.9.1, im trying with 10.15.1 now, will let you know

Comment: it works fine with node 10.15.1 as well. This leads me to think its a problem with soemthing upstream, ie whatever is calling your mongoConnect function

Comment: that's a bummer - any suggestions on a good way to troubleshoot that?  I would say I can paste the whole app.js code in here, but that doesn't seem like good etiquette and it'll probably exceed the character limit.  Or maybe it's the Mongo version?  I'm currently using 4.0.5.

Comment: That warning started in 8.2.1. Both versions should return it I think. Also, maybe you can use www.repl.it for a Node online sandbox debug

Comment: @Rashomon I pasted the whole app.js in an edit up top.  I was thinking maybe having bluebird in there screwed up the native promises or something, but apparently if you use async/await, bluebird is ignored altogether, so commenting the bluebird part out has the same result.

Comment: Im using mongo 3.4 and mongodb npm 3.1.13. Best way to trouble shoot it would be to just call that file the way I did before my edit, from another standalone file outside your app completely. If it still does it there then I really dont know what would be causing it, but im sure youll kick yourself when you finally figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling connect from `app.js` in a sync way, So your `async/await` methods wont work. You can test it using a `sleep` function:

```
let sleep = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Finished sleeping');
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  })
}

exports.mongoConnect = async (dbName, archiveDbName, userName, password) => {
  await sleep() // sleep two seconds
  // rest of your mongoConnect code
})
```

Then add a log in `app.js` after the connection:

```
mongoUtil.mongoConnect('myDb', 'myArchiveDb', 'username', 'password');
console.log('Finished connection');
```

You will obtain the following output in console:

```
Finished connection // You can see the code doesnt wait to mongo to connect
[After 2 seconds]
Finished sleeping // After this sleep log it will start connecting...
```

To solve this you would need to execute `app.js` in an async way:

**Be advice top-level async functions are not recommended, but I want you to see the error**

```
(async () => {
    // rest of your app.js
    await mongoUtil.mongoConnect('myDb', 'myArchiveDb', 'username', 'password');
    console.log('Finished connection attempt');
    // rest of your app.js
})()
```

And then the error Im getting at console is (No warnings!):

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
Error connecting to the MongoDb database at URL: mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb
Finished connection attempt
```

Comment: After a huge research now I realize calling `mongoUtil.mongoConnect` in a sync way doesnt throw any warning for me...